# Does not include the specified expression as part of aggregate view - What does it mean?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I used the following code which Gives me the error

"Your query does not include the specified expression 'Remaining' as part of aggregate view"

```
SELECT
    [Insurance Policy Coverage].[Retention]-Sum([Net Invoice amount Approved]) AS Remaining,
    [Vendor Matter Detail].[Chubb Claim number], 
    [Insurance Policy Coverage].Retention, 
    [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID]
FROM 
    (
        [List of Law Firms] INNER JOIN 
        (
            (
                [Database] INNER JOIN [Invoice Entries] ON 
                Database.[Short Name] = [Invoice Entries].[Short Name]
            )
            INNER JOIN [Invoice Payment Processing] ON 
            Database.[Short Name] = [Invoice Payment Processing].[Short Name]
        )
        ON 
        ([List of Law Firms].[Law Firm] = [Invoice Entries].Vendor) AND 
        ([List of Law Firms].[Law Firm] = Database.[Law Firm].Value)
    )
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        [Insurance Policy Coverage] INNER JOIN [Vendor Matter Detail] ON
        ([Insurance Policy Coverage].[Insurance Policy ID] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID]) AND 
        ([Insurance Policy Coverage].[Insurance Policy ID] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID]) AND 
        ([Insurance Policy Coverage].[Insurance Policy ID] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID])
    )
    ON
    (Database.[Short Name] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Short Name]) AND 
    (Database.[Short Name] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Short Name])
GROUP BY 
    [Vendor Matter Detail].[Chubb Claim number], 
    [Insurance Policy Coverage].Retention, 
    [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID];
```

However, I use a similar code for a simple mock database it works just fine -

```
SELECT 
    [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit]-Sum([Net Invoice Amount]) AS Remaining, 
    [Matter Detail].[Claim Number], 
    [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit], 
    [Matter Detail].Policy
FROM 
    (
        (
            [Main Database] INNER JOIN [Matter Detail] 
            ON [Main Database].[Database ID] = [Matter Detail].[Short Name]
        ) 
        INNER JOIN [Payment Processing] ON 
        ([Main Database].[Database ID] = [Payment Processing].[Short Name]) AND
        ([Matter Detail].[Matter Detail ID] = [Payment Processing].[Matter Detail ID])
    ) 
    INNER JOIN [Insurance Coverage] ON 
    [Matter Detail].Policy = [Insurance Coverage].[Insurance ID]
GROUP BY 
    [Matter Detail].[Claim Number], 
    [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit], 
    [Matter Detail].Policy;
```

I am new to Microsoft Access - I have read several FAQ and the common conclusion was All fields in the `SELECT` field list must either be included in the `GROUP BY` clause or be included as arguments to an SQL aggregate function.

But, For me it seems like there is some other error; please advise the possible reasons for such error.

I appreciate your time and thank you in advance; let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved - 
One of the reason why My code was throwing the error was because of the unnecessary and complex relationships between tables. The Error stopped after I removed the unnecessarily links between the table - Here is the Final code I used

```
SELECT [Insurance Policy Coverage].Retention-Sum([Net Invoice amount Approved]) AS Remaining, 
       [Vendor Matter Detail].[Chubb Claim number], 
       [Insurance Policy Coverage].Retention, 
       [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID]
FROM 
       (
         [Insurance Policy Coverage] INNER JOIN [Vendor Matter Detail]  
        ON [Insurance Policy Coverage].[Insurance Policy ID] = [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID]
        ) 
         INNER JOIN 
       (
          ([Database] INNER JOIN [Invoice Entries] 
           ON Database.[Short Name] = [Invoice Entries].[Short Name]
          ) 
          INNER JOIN [Invoice Payment Processing] 
     ON [Invoice Entries].[Invoice Entry ID] = [Invoice Payment Processing].[Invoice Entries ID]
       ) 
     ON [Vendor Matter Detail].[Vendor Matter ID] = [Invoice Entries].[Vendor Matter ID]
GROUP BY [Vendor Matter Detail].[Chubb Claim number], 
         [Insurance Policy Coverage].Retention, 
         [Vendor Matter Detail].[Insurance Policy Coverage ID];
```